# Changing Odd Text String to Date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Have a text string that I need to convert to date, however, it's not the generic yyyymmdd string. e.g. March 2018 is stored as '2018m3' as are all other dates. Is there a way to convert the string to a normal date in Oracle?

Comment: What does October look like?

Comment: October is '2018m10'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be helpful :

```
SQL> SELECT to_date('2018m3', 'YYYY"m"MM') FROM dual
  2  /
```

Output

```
TO_DATE('2018M3','YYYY"M"MM')
-----------------------------
3/1/2018
```

Comment: IMO, this time s the correct answer, as it’s converting the string to a date in one function call, so should be quicker than using multiple functions (including concatenation) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the format, you can do:

```
select add_months(to_date(substr(col, 1, 4) || '0101'),
                  to_number(replace(substr(col, -2), 'm', '')) - 1
                 )
```

An alternative method:

```
select to_date(substr(col, 1, 4) || regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]+', 1, 2), 'YYYYMM')
```